# Weird performance test result

Tags: c#, performance-testing, profiler

I've been working on a DICOM viewer. It is currently working correctly. Furthermore, when I tried to convert the slices to a 3D model the process took about 3-4 minutes. After some profiling, it now takes less than a minute. However, there is something weird about the result of the last performance test I made:
[image: 21.2%]

May I know why a brace is consuming that much Performance??

EDIT: the closing brace consumes 1.5% too, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean the whole function.

Comment: Can it be that a method as a *whole routine* consumes 21.2% per cent? In other words `{...}` *scope* consumes 21.2%?

Comment: No, the result shows that the whole function consumes 38.2%, 21.2% of which are the curly braces!

Comment: Do you use AOP (postsharp example)? Are you profiling the correct build (ie. profiled code is in sync with source code)?

Comment: I don't know what AOP is, and I'm profiling the latest build. I rebuilt and retested and the result is the same.

Comment: How do you measure? Sampling, Instrumentation, something completely different?

Comment: Just CPU Sampling

Comment: As far as I understand, at each sample the call stack will be examined, so in case you have complex computation within `GetHoundsfieldPixelValue` but there are no inner function calls, the sampler will associate the sample point with the current function, but it will not examine the exact current instruction within the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you meant exactly, but In each line of code there is a percentage of sampling according to the processing power it consumes.

Comment: Maybe you need to give more information about the code. Specifically the ratio of *now often* the function is called and *how much it does*. If the function is called very often and does very little, then actually the function entry and exit might consume more time than the computation within. But I'm kinda fishing in murky waters here

Comment: Actually, This function is called about 87,500,000 times(about 350 images, each 500x500, once for each pixel). That's a problem yeah?

Comment: Have a look at [Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx), specially "Table 1 Primitive Times" there. Look at the times for method calls (static, instance, inlined, virtual and so on) and for the primitives to get a feeling for the implications. If you do little work within the function, be sure to inline it! (don't take the presented data literally though... its just a little hint on relative performace to be expected between different operations)

Comment: I found the solution. In-lining is automatically made when the solution configuration is set to Release. Doing that made the program much faster.